# Pandas combine two rows adding only a single value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a set of data and found two rows that need to be combined on a single value.  I ran the following:

```
pd.concat(g for _, g in cityData_df.groupby("city") if len(g) > 1)
```

And got the following:

```
        city        driver_count    type
84      Port James  15              Suburban
100     Port James  3               Suburban
```

How can I combine these two rows in cityData_df so there is only one entry for Port James with 18 drivers?

Comment: try `df.groupby('city')['driver_count'].agg(sum)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
cityData_df.groupby(['city', 'type'])['driver_count'].sum().reset_index()
```

Comment: Appreciate it.  Verified: cityData_df.loc[cityData_df['city'] == "Port James"]